# Stuck on Victus when he crashed

Tags: mass-effect-3

I am stuck on Lieutenant Victus. It says that I'm right next to it but I have to jump over a wall that it will not let me jump! I'm so frustrated, can anyone help?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot where you're stuck?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar incident on Clear the Camp where I knocked a Brute outside the base.  I was able to snipe him for a while but eventually he wouldn't come out and play, I had to restart the level.

There are a few of these locations where back tracking just a little would make life so much easier.

Comment: I also got stuck in exactly the same place. I am restarting level now and hoping for the best.

Comment: The restart of the mission worked. I may have missed a harvester that "retreated" then in the area where the wall I got stuck was at, the "stuck" time I played there were no enemies, the restart time it was full of enemies, and once cleared, it went right into a cut scene. Obviously when I was stuck I failed to trigger something that would spawn those enemies. (bug) Its a short mission so a replay is the quickest fix. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that happened to me once. The notifier said I was right next to him, but I just kept moving forward. You can restart the mission if you are truly stuck or find a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. I had to restart the mission. If you don't kill that second harvester none of the stuff after that unlocks.

Answer (score 0):

Run into that on my 3rd playthrough, restarting didn't help me, at least I found exactly why :> Old post, but maybe it will help someone.

Quoting noxiuniversitas1 from Bioware forums:
Sorry to bump this thread, but I thought I would corroborate the occurence of this bug. I ran into it on my 4th X360 playthrough. It occurs if you manage to kill the second harvester instead of scare it off. This is easier than it sounds, especially if you're a biotic user with Liara and Javik. I was running the second harvester encounter on insanity - had to do it 4 times before I managed to wound the harvester enough without killing it. Most frustrating bug I've encountered in ME3 to date!

Oh, and to clarify, U cannot kill it only the 1st time U encounter it. It doesn't matter if U do when it shows up later, after it flew away 1st time.